# OS X Scheme Language (dialect for lisp)

Tags: macos, scheme, lisp

I've only learned Python, and have recently begun to learn a new language called Scheme. I have a few basic questions regarding Scheme. 1) If I want to open a scm file on sublime text 2, can I just select "Lisp" for my language settings? 2 To run python on terminal, all I had to do was python file.py, what command do i do to open a scm. file on my os x.

Comment: I would suggest using [Racket](http://racket-lang.org) if you are not tied to any specific implementation. It comes with an IDE and everything you need to get started.

Comment: @uselpa locking in right away without questioning the need? I'd go with R6RS + SRFI keepig it compatible with other implementations as far as I could. I would still use DrRacket though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Yes. You could also install a more [Scheme oriented version](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Racket).
2) Yes. Depends on the implementation. For [racket](http://racket-lang.org/download/) you can start with `plt-r6rs-script file.scm`, `plt-r5rs-script file.scm` or you can compile `raco exe file.scm` and then just run `file` which then is a executable. Racket also had an IDE called DrRacket suitable for programming, debugging and running in the IDE and it supports standard Scheme versions such as R5RS, R6RS as well as it's own languages racket, typed racket and lazy racket. Don't confuse the language racket with the whole imlementation with the very same name that also runs Scheme very well.

For ikarus you do `ikarus --r6rs-script file.scm`

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to pick up a Scheme dialect, you may want to do it via [Racket](http://racket-lang.org/). At that point, if you're comfortable with the terminal, you can go through their [Systems Programming With Racket](http://docs.racket-lang.org/more/index.html) tutorial, which will clarify how you'd go about editing and running scheme files from a command line.